# Is there an alternative for webbrowser control in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I implemented a browser using webbrowser control (WP7). I want to add some features but this control has a lot of limitations. For example it is not possible to modify cookie, access postdata from request, etc. I need a lot of workarounds to implement features different from simple navigation. I notice that some people use httpwebrequest... is it possible to display the response without using webbrowser? Is there a more flexible alternative to this control?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you actually want to do. Do you need to present something to the user? Do you want to access the underlying data while he is browsing?

`HttpRequest`/`HttpResponse` are used whenever you want to initiate a request from your code i.e. without a user actually navigating to something. This is for machine-machine communication, not for user-machine interaction.

When you give us an example of what you want to build, we can give more detailed answer.